# Nativescript won't run on Android

Tags: nativescript

I've been using my application on the Nativescript Playground for android, it seems to be working fine, but when i try to run this on my android emulator it just doesn't bundle.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

null

Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

**TNS Doctor**

```html
√ Getting environment information

No issues were detected.
√ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
√ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
√ The Android SDK is installed.
√ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
√ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
√ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
√ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 6.7.8 version and is up to date.
‼ Update available for component tns-core-modules. Your current version is 6.5.5 and the latest available version is 6.5.8.
‼ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 6.5.0 and the latest available version is 6.5.1.
‼ Update available for component tns-ios. Your current version is 6.5.0 and the latest available version is 6.5.1.
```

I've tried using different SDK versions, removing my Gradle folders and changing the properties in **AndroidManifest.xml** but it doesn't works at all.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
null

Comment: Try to delete whole `platforms` and `hooks` (if exists) directories and run build again.

Comment: @deoomen Thanks for replying, i've tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check this link if it helps you http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=942

Comment: @UsmanAli It didn't worked for my current project, cause there was so many plugins using Google Service to check for, so i just copied src folder in a empty {N} Vue project and i got this working again!!! Thank you